# Issue with @media rule

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I was at work making a page and i put my @media rules in a responsive.css file. So it worked all fine, until i uploaded to server and the responsive.css is still being called but none of its rules are working. i also found this to be the case at home as well. Any ideas why this might be?

below is my links i used.
and the responsive.css file.

again this works at work but not anywhere else, the styles .css works fine so does my jquery scripts.
Thanks in advance

(unable to show full code for CopyR reasons)

```css
mobilenav {
  display: none;
  font-size: 450%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1em;
  z-index: 10;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: var(--katlgreen);
}

mobilenav h1 {
  background-color: transparent;
}

navmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: var(--katdgreen);
  z-index: 9;
}

navmenu a {
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-weight: 900;
}


/* columns and removes */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  td {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  column {
    width: 48%;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  column {
    width: 98%;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  #estlogo {
    display: none;
  }
  brandbuttons {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  tab {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    background-color: var(--katlgreen);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    height: 5em;
    align-content: center;
  }
  mobilenav {
    display: flex;
  }
  #katlogo {
    margin: auto 5%;
  }
}


/* columns and removes */

@media only screen and (min-width: 951px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  nav {
    width: 50%;
  }
  tabline {
    width: 55%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 950px) {
  .brandbutton2 {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .brandbuttons2 {
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #katlogo {
    width: 120px;
  }
  #estlogo {
    width: 80px;
  }
  nav {
    width: 50%;
  }
  tabline {
    width: 55%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 749px) {
  * {
    font-size: 98%;
  }
  .brandbutton2 {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .brandbuttons2 {
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    width: 80%;
  }
  tabline {
    width: 85%;
  }
  #katlogo {
    width: 120px;
  }
  #estlogo {
    width: 80px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 359px) {
  * {
    font-size: 98%;
  }
  #katlogo {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  * {
    font-size: 96%;
  }
  #katlogo {
    width: 80px;
  }
}


/* mobile change hdr tab to menu complete
/* vs device delete second logo and remove 2 buttons. complete
```

```html
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="functions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: What kind of element is `<mobilenav>`?

Comment: mobilenav is a custom sematic css tag. mobilenav is supposed to appear in the top right corner which is toggleable to open a menu for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best method i found to fix this soulution is adding the following meta code for mobile responsiveness.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use `min-width` instead of `max-width`

Comment: some of the elements such as 'mobilenav' & 'column' are used as sematic css, which wont appear or change when the @media rule requirements are met. The #estlogo still appearing in the top right which should display as none below 450px. Regards

Comment: perhaps use `min-width` instead of `max-width`

Comment: strangely that does work thankyou. i did try swapping the sematic css to classes in div tags but wasnt working still. However it dosent want to change from the lowest css viewport, il try seeing if theres any errors

Comment: @ckwheatley15 please mark my answer as the answer, i did update it.